# Getting improper resultcode while using Zxing BarCode application in my android application

Tags: android, zxing

I tried to use this IntentIntegrator approach, but in my onActivityResult() I am getting **resultcode = 49374 requestCode = 49374**, I don't understand what am I missing, FYI, I only included IntentIntegrator.java and IntentResult.java in my project.

Comment: if you post your code we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are perhaps printing out `requestCode` twice. 49374 (0xC0DE) is the correct `requestCode`. The app only sets `Activity.RESULT_OK` or `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` as the `resultCode`. You can check the source in `android/`.